# Test custom hook with react-hooks-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-hooks-testing-library

I am trying to write tests for this custom hook using react-hooks-testing-library.

```
import { deleteArticleById } from '../../API/articles/deleteArticleById';
const useArticleDelete = () => {
  const [articleId, setArticleId] = useState(null);
  const setArticleIdToDelete = id => {
    setArticleId(id);
  };

  const deleteArticle = useCallback(
    async () => {
      if (!articleId) {
        return;
      }

      try {
        await deleteArticleById(articleId);
        setArticleId(null);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    },
    [articleId]
  );

  return { articleId, setArticleIdToDelete, deleteArticle };
};

export default useArticleDelete;
```

Here are my tests

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import { deleteArticleById } from '../../API/articles/deleteArticleById';
import useArticleDelete from './useArticleDelete';

jest.mock('../../API/articles/deleteArticleById');

describe('useArticleDelete', () => {
  test('should use ArticleDelete', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useArticleDelete())
    act(() => {
      result.current.setArticleIdToDelete(1)
    })
    expect(result.current.articleId).toBe(1)
  });

  test('should delete article', async () => {
    deleteArticleById.mockResolvedValue({});
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useArticleDelete())
    act(() => {
      result.current.deleteArticle()
    })
    expect(result.current.articleId).toBeNull()
  })
});
```

Test "should delete article" is written, but the they don't cover lines of code between try..catch in deleteArticle function in useArticleDelete hook.

Please help my out to find out that i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use await before you call the `deleteArticle` method as it is an async call. Function will return nothin until it finished the execution of `await deleteArticleById(articleId);` so you need to wait until it gets executed.

```
test('should delete article', async () => {
    deleteArticleById.mockResolvedValue({});
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useArticleDelete())
    await result.current.deleteArticle()
    expect(result.current.articleId).toBeNull()
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. But what about if deleteArticleById returns an error. Is it a right way to test this?  test('should throw error', async () => {
    deleteArticleById.mockRejectedValue(new Error)
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useArticleDelete())
    try {
      await result.current.deleteArticle()
    } catch (e) {
     expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(Error)
    }
  })

Comment: Thats right you can test it like you said